# Is it possible to sort the results of db.list()?

Tags: node.js, database, cloudant

I am trying to get a list of all the documents in a cloudant database using db.list() and it works just fine. But I'd like to know if it's possible to sort these documents using an index I previously added. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Data returned from a Cloudant view can be ordered ascending or descending on the key. In the node client library, `db.list()` translates to a call to the `_all_docs` endpoint which is a system view keyed on `_id`. When using either the `all_docs` view -- or any of your own views -- you can change the returned ordering direction using the `descending` parameter:

```
curl "https://acc.cloudant.com/db/_design/ddoc/_view/by_title?desceding=true" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

In the client library, if you use [db.view](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#views-and-design-functions) to fetch data from your view, you should be able to pass the `descending` parameter with it.

General view API docs here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-using-views